# Create underline after last line of text to fill white space

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, next.js

I'm having trouble with a SCSS/CSS styling idea, I want to fill the space before or after the last line of a heading with a solid line. The last line of text does not have a set width (it varies depending on screen size) I'm open to any suggestions.

Here's what I want to achieve when the text is aligned right or left.

```
|Here is some text on screen|     |Here is some text on screen|
|very cool -----------------|  or |----------------- very cool|
|                           |     |                           |
|                           |     |                           |
```

EDIT Code added for clarity:

HTML

```
<h1>You're the painter, we just want to see you paint.</h1>
```

CSS (that is how far I've got)

```
h1{
  font-family: "doesntMatter";
  font-style: bold;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-align: left;
}

h1::after{
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 2.5rem;
  border-bottom: 10px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  content: "";
}
```

Comment: Please show us your relevant HTML. Do you want it as a solid line or as dashes?

Comment: Please put code direct into your question not in a comment - and show relevant CSS too. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: sorry, the code has been added, I don't think I am anywhere near a solution, I would like it to be a solid line, like an underline but just within the negative space that does not contain any text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem, if you take this code here and run it, the last line will be struck through.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-inline: 2rem;
}

.text {
  font-style: bold;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  line-height: 2.5rem;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}

.text::after {
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  bottom: 0.9rem;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 0.4rem solid #000;
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
      <h1 class="text">You're the painter, we are just the paint, brushes and canvas</h1>
    </section>
```

But if you remove `left:0;` from the `text::after` styling, it magically jumps over to fill the blank space at the end.

I added a `margin-left: 1rem` to give the things some breathing room but yea I really don't know what's going on.

I don't know how it works but it just kind of does, if the `.text{}` element has `overflow-x: hidden` applied to it then the effect will cutoff at the width of the header.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-inline: 2rem;
}

.text {
  font-style: bold;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  line-height: 2.5rem;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.text::after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0.9rem;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  border-bottom: 0.4rem solid #000;
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <h1 class="text">You're the painter, we are just the paint, brushes and canvas</h1>
</section>
```

That is one way to do the effect, if you want the line to spill off the page, you apply `overflow-x: hidden` to the `.container{}` element and remove if from the `.text{}`... since my container is 100% width the line goes off the page and works as intended.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-inline: 2rem;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.text {
  font-style: bold;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  line-height: 2.5rem;
  position: relative;

}

.text::after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0.9rem;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  border-bottom: 0.4rem solid #000;
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <h1 class="text">You're the painter, we are just the paint, brushes and canvas</h1>
</section>
```

The line responds to any changes in the width of the last line. There's a few edge cases that I'm going to have to look into like if the last line of text practically fills the entire width of the header, then there's just a little nub at the end.

But it's been fixed! I hope this helps anyone in the future that couldn't figure out the right combination of words to google to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Building on what you have already, this snippet puts the text within a span element. This enables a white padding which can overwrite that part of the red line which is under the actual text.

```css
h1 {
  font-family: "doesntMatter";
  font-style: bold;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
}

h1>span::after {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 10px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: -11px;
  content: "X";
  color: transparent;
  z-index: -1;
}

h1>span {
  background: white;
  padding-bottom: 11px;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>You're the painter, we just want to see you paint.</span></h1>
```

Note - it's a little bit hacky, including positioning 1px different from the height of the line. This is because on modern screens which use more than one screen pixel for a CSS pixel the system can 'leave behind' traces of color when it is positioning (e.g. a screen pixel - not a whole CSS pixel).

Comment: Interesting, I like the approach, I'm going to keep mashing my head at it because I'd like to get this effect without the background color, because on my site it is very noticeable